What is value of this resistor? Color code is weird
I have a SMPS to repair, it's a Dell Branded PC power supply.
There is a resistor inside nearby the power MOSFET, it's 5 band color code is Brown-Black-Gold-Gold-Silver.
Can someone please guide me?


Seems to be related to this question; Silver probably marks a "special" kind of resistor. What do you measure?

Google found for me this where brown, black, gold is 10 * 0.1 Ohm --> 1 Ohm, the next gold is probably 5% tolerance, and silver is the temperature coefficient? Black is 250 ppm, so gold is guessed 500 ppm/K and silver is guessed 1000 ppm/K --> would make 5% at 50K temperature change = same as tolerance --> reasonable, SMPS should be produced cheap... so 5...10% tolerance ok. PS: SMPS of how many Watt?

@BitLauncher From the link you've provided, the 5th band might also be an indicator of the "reliability of the resistor".

@Velvet, right I did not read it in detail. Now I read it. The reliability is used in military applications and AFAIK its parts are more expensive, IMHO not used in SMPSs. So I still assume that the fifth ring is the temperature coefficient - what is confirmed in this site, see Five band resistors with a fourth band of gold or silver form an exception and are used on specialized and older resistors. The first ..., the 4th is the tolerance, and the 5th is the temperature coefficient (ppm/˚C).
